# Displaying common HTML in Express and Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, express

Im wondering how one would display common html header information in an Express application.  Im trying to have a common menu or header displayed on my web app across all pages but cant figure out how to do this without copy and pasting the html into every html file on my server.  I believe this can be done with routes.  my app is structured like so:

```
/ web root
   - server.js // main web server
   /public
     - css, 3rd party js files, images
   /routes
     - index.js includes renders to seperate pages
   /views
     - jade and html files.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jade then you actually won't do this with a route, instead you'll use Layouts. If you used the express-cli tool to generate your project then you'll notice the views/homepage.jade file uses the layout.jade file to do what you're expecting.

If you want a more complex example, here's a demo project I made that's based on Bootstrap: https://github.com/newz2000/template-test-jade

In either case, the idea is you have a file that uses a syntax like this:

```
extends layout

block content
    your page's content here
```

Then your layout.jade file will have a line like this:

```
block content
```

When you res.render() the first file, it will first render layout and take the `block content` from the layout.jade file and replace it with the contents of your page.

Two other things to consider:

1. Handlebars.js is a more HTML-like templating language that supports layouts and partials, so you can utilize that to your goal. There are a couple steps to get it working, but it's not hard. I've documented it here: http://www.bearfruit.org/2014/01/20/node-js-showdown-handlebars-compared/
2. Just use plain static HTML files. Yeah, you lose the ability to have Node.js manage the common headers, but you get plain ol' HTML. You can drop an index.html into your public folder and then make sure there is no route that conflicts with it and it will be served as your homepage.

Comment: ugh jade, i really prefer HTML but i guess i can learn jade. Is this the only way to do this? Do you know if you can use jade and HTML?

Comment: Jade and HTML don't play well together, but you can easily switch to a different view engine that does. One downside is that, when it comes to supporting partials and layouts, Jade is one of the best integrated. However, Handlebars.js does support it, I wrote a blog post about it here: http://www.bearfruit.org/2014/01/20/node-js-showdown-handlebars-compared/ and the only non-HTML tags you'd need is the {} tags to utilize the layouts and/or partials. This is common for single-page apps that use Backbone or Angular.

Comment: Another option you have it to put a plain .html file into your public folder. If you create index.html and then don't include a view for the homepage, it will serve the static file properly. If this works for you, I'll update my answer to mention this. This will not give you reusable bits for the header though.

Comment: cool, thanks newz. Can you add the html option to your answer? i might just end up using jade. I just dont like the syntax haha

Comment: Certainly. I too don't care for the syntax, but if you want an optimistic perspective, the one benefit is the syntax is very clean and concise. When it's all done it's a bit amazing to see how compact and readable the files are. ;-)

Comment: true.  It doesnt help that there is not that much support online for it.

Comment: Is there a way to have a common layout jade file that all my pages can reference? If i have a file deep in some subdirectory that wants to reference the layout.jade file i have to "../../" all the way back to root to extend it

Comment: I'm afraid you've exhausted my knowledge on the subject. That is a mysterious problem and is worthy of it's own question.